# Copy and paste data in visible cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA and I would like to cut the data available below the header column from columns L to S and paste it in Columns D to K in the same sheet. Please note that it is a filtered range and the data should be cut from and pasted in the visible cells only. Also, please note that the header column should not be included. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column L
ws.Range("L2:S" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'copy visible cells
ws.Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
'paste into D1
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Further to your recent comments, I believe the following will do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column L
Set Rng = ws.Range("L2:S" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each cell In Rng
    cell.Copy ws.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -8)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi  Xabier! Thank you so much for your help! I tried using the code you gave, but the data is getting pasted in the first row. Also, it is getting pasted in the invisible cells as well. However, the cells that have to be copied are being copied right. To make it more clear for you, if the filtered row numbers are 47, 60, 63 and 82, I need data to be copied from ranges 47, 60, 63 and 82 from columns L to S and they have to be pasted in ranges 47, 60, 63 and 82 from columns D to K. Please let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: Also, I tried something at my end. But I'm not sure how to paste the data below the header cells in columns D to K. Hope this gives you more clarity: Range("S1").Select   
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$105").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("L1:S1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1, Selection.Columns.Count).Cut
     With Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range
       Range("D" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
    End With

Comment: OMG!  You are a genius, Xabier! That worked perfect!! Thank you sooooooooooooo much!! :)

Comment: @Pret, please do mark my response as an answer if it has helped. Thank you :)

Comment: I was just about to do it, Xabier! But I'm not sure how to do it! I tried searching the forum but did not find any guideline! Can you please let me know how I should mark your reply as an answer?

Comment: Sorry for being naive! I'm pretty new here!

Comment: Found it!! Thank you! :)